# Possible for ffmpeg to downsample over time, serve RTSP?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to take an RSTP webcam, downsample the video to a lower rate (say one frame every 5 seconds) and serve the result as an RTSP stream.
Is is possible to configure ffmpeg (or libffmpeg) to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all we have to do is adding `-r 0.2` argument, and re-encode the video.

It is also recommended to add `-tune zerolatency` or `-g 1` for making sure every frame is a key frame (required in case video latency is relevant).

---

Example:
Receiving RTSP stream from localhost, and streaming at 0.2fps (to localhost with different port):

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 1000000 -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:10000/live.stream -r 0.2 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:20000/live.stream
```

---

Testing:
For testing I simulated the RTSP camera with FFmpeg (streaming synthetic video at 25fps).
The RTSP stream is captured by another FFmpeg process that reduces the rate to 0.2fps.
The 0.2fps video is captured and displayed using FFprobe.

The test is implemented as a batch file:

```
::Play the video for testing
start ffplay -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport tcp -flags low_delay -vf setpts=0 -listen_timeout 1000000 rtsp://127.0.0.1:20000/live.stream

::Wait 5 seconds
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul

::Capture the RTSP camera at 25fps, convert to 0.2fps (with re-encoding)
start ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 1000000 -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:10000/live.stream -r 0.2 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:20000/live.stream

::Wait 5 seconds
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul

::Simulate an RTSP camera at 25fps
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 30 -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://127.0.0.1:10000/live.stream
```

---

It starts awkward and gets stable after few frames.
(We mat use `select` filter for solving it).

Sample frames:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]